# looking for ftp client or web browser which can assign network interface

Tags: linux, ftp, eth0, web

Does anyone know of an ftp client (or web browser), which allows me to specify (or assign) a network interface explicitly (like eth1 for example) during usage? Something for Linux would be good.

Comment: You want to control which interface your ftp traffic goes out?

Answer (score 4):

The **[wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)** command provides the `--bind-address` parameter and **[curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)** provides `--interface`, perhaps these will do what you want.

Comment: There is a tool called `wput` that is the opposite of `wget`, allowing for upload of files - the other half of FTP, though I've never used that tool.